# MySQL - Using SELECT INTO statement inside cursor in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I am writing stored procedure in MySQL database using cursor to iterate on records. I am able to fetch records inside variables specified in FETCH statement, but when I use SELECT inside cursor, I am not able to store result in variables. I know its possible but can't find out why its not working in below MySQL code.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_monthly_leave_entitlement`
(IN `emp` INT(10), OUT `experience` INT(10), OUT `entitlement` DECIMAL(10,4)) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 

DECLARE emp_no INT(10);
DECLARE current_month_exp INT(10);
DECLARE previous_month_end_exp INT(10);
DECLARE emp_status INT(10);

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE monthly_entitlement decimal(8,4) DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE emp_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT e.`emp_number` AS emp_no, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, e.`joined_date` , NOW( ) ) AS month_start_exp, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, e.`joined_date`, LAST_DAY(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ) AS last_month_end_exp, e.`emp_status` AS emp_status 
FROM `hs_hr_employee` AS e 
WHERE e.`termination_id` is null AND e.`emp_number`=emp;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN emp_cursor;

read_loop : LOOP
FETCH emp_cursor INTO emp_no, current_month_exp, previous_month_end_exp, emp_status;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    /*Monthly entitlement as per experience*/       
    SELECT `monthly_entitlement` INTO monthly_entitlement 
    FROM `ohrm_leave_entitlement_conf` 
    WHERE `year_completion` = IF(previous_month_end_exp >4 , 5, previous_month_end_exp) 
    AND `leave_type_id` = 4;

   SET experience = previous_month_end_exp;
   SET entitlement = monthly_entitlement;

END LOOP;

CLOSE emp_cursor;
END
```

Not able to get value inside **monthly_entitlement** or **entitlement**, the value is always **0.0000**. 
I tried to run monthly entitlement query in separate procedure, it returns correct value. I have match data types of table column and variables.

Can somebody help me to understand what is wrong here ?

Comment: To debug this put a select in after the if done..endif statement to display what's coming from the cursor to the local variables and proceed from there. BTW I would avoid giving local variables the same name as table columns and would give them a prefix (such as lv_) to clarify code.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid naming local variables as columns name, see [Chapter 2 Restrictions on Stored Programs :: Name Conflicts within Stored Routines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html). Try changing the following:

```sql
...
-- DECLARE monthly_entitlement decimal(8,4) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE _monthly_entitlement decimal(8,4) DEFAULT 0;
...
/*Monthly entitlement as per experience*/
-- SELECT `monthly_entitlement` INTO monthly_entitlement
SELECT `monthly_entitlement` INTO _monthly_entitlement
...
-- SET entitlement = monthly_entitlement;
SET entitlement = _monthly_entitlement;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others the Name of the local variable and the column name should be different, So here the changes

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_monthly_leave_entitlement`
(IN `emp` INT(10), OUT `experience` INT(10), OUT `entitlement` DECIMAL(10,4)) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 

DECLARE v_emp_no INT(10);
DECLARE v_current_month_exp INT(10);
DECLARE v_previous_month_end_exp INT(10);
DECLARE v_emp_status INT(10);

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE v_monthly_entitlement decimal(8,4) DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE emp_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT e.`emp_number` AS emp_no, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, e.`joined_date` , NOW( ) ) AS month_start_exp, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, e.`joined_date`, LAST_DAY(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ) AS last_month_end_exp, e.`emp_status` AS emp_status 
FROM `hs_hr_employee` AS e 
WHERE e.`termination_id` is null AND e.`emp_number`=emp;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN emp_cursor;

read_loop : LOOP
FETCH emp_cursor INTO v_emp_no, v_current_month_exp, v_previous_month_end_exp, v_emp_status;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    /*Monthly entitlement as per experience*/       
    SELECT `monthly_entitlement` INTO v_monthly_entitlement 
    FROM `ohrm_leave_entitlement_conf` 
    WHERE `year_completion` = IF(v_previous_month_end_exp >4 , 5, v_previous_month_end_exp) 
    AND `leave_type_id` = 4;

   SET experience = v_previous_month_end_exp;
   SET entitlement = v_monthly_entitlement;

END LOOP;

CLOSE emp_cursor;
END
```